# DBD::mysql (Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC) error from running perl script with perl-support.vim (Ended up just being an incorrectly set PERL5LIB)

Tags: perl, vim, perlbrew, vim-perl

I'm attempting a short script that accesses a Mysql database. I've installed the relevant perl modules, DBI and DBD::mysql and their dependencies as far as I know.

This is the only code in test.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;
```

Running it at the command line with 'perl test.pl' runs fine without error.

However, when I attempt to run it through perlsupport in vim using "\rr" I receive an error.

> Can't locate DBD/mysql.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Users/rob/perl5/lib/perl5/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Users/rob/perl5/lib/perl5 /Users/rob/perl5/lib/perl5 setenv PERLBREW_MANPATH /Users/rob/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/man setenv PERLBREW_PATH /Users/rob/perl5/perlbrew/bin /Users/rob/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin setenv PERLBREW_PERL perl-5.16.0 setenv PERLBREW_ROOT /Users/rob/perl5/perlbrew setenv PERLBREW_VERSION 0.69 setenv PERLBREW_MANPATH /Users/rob/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/man setenv PERLBREW_PATH /Users/rob/perl5/perlbrew/bin /Users/rob/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin setenv PERLBREW_PERL perl-5.16.0 setenv PERLBREW_ROOT /Users/rob/perl5/perlbrew setenv PERLBREW_VERSION 0.69 /Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.16 /Network/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.16 /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.16.2 /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.16 /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.16 .) at /Users/rob/Desktop/perl/test.pl line 11.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /Users/rob/Desktop/perl/test.pl line 11.

I'm using perlbrew on OSX and using a perlbrew installed Perl 5.16.0 version and I've set up Local::Lib for modules. I've looked through all the settings, and even attempted un/reinstalling the perlbrew perl 5.16.0 installation and un/reinstalled DBI and DBD::mysql to see if I screwed up in my set up.

The "setenv XXXXXXX" seem out of place in the @INC, so I may have screwed up the set up.

**Edit**

So I ended up finding the issue. My PERL5LIB variable was being set incorrectly somewhere else (hobbs was right), so I have it set correctly in my fish.config file now. I still need to hunt down where that issue is, but this specific issue is solved.

Comment: I agree with the last line of your question. That stuff doesn't belong there. I think your `PERL5LIB` is set incorrectly.

Comment: Why would use use both Local::Lib and perlbrew??